# Call Java Method from API in .NET

Tags: c#, java, pinvoke

I have a Java API in jar file with some dependencies from other jar files.

Is there any way to call a specific method from this API, like using PInvoke from .NET?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go :) I've used it myself and was very please with the implementation.

[IKVM: Using Java API's in .NET Applications](http://www.ikvm.net/devguide/net2java.html)

- (1) If you just want some libraries
  from Java.
- (2.1) If you have access to
  the code.
- (2.2) Last resort,
  dynamically load the Java into .Net
  (interpreter)

Comment: By using IKVM, do you know how to specify other jar files (Class path)?

Comment: You can use http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html which states you can supply multiple jar files :)

Comment: Hi, API that I'm trying to convert is for processing wav files and somewhere it throws exception when it calls javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File file). Exception message is "could not get audio input stream from input file". I have called the same method with same file from Java and it works fine, something causing this in .NET. Do you know what could it be? Some problem with permission?

Comment: @aumanets I could be something with permissions but it could also be ikvm´s converting. Unfortunately I can't help you :/ Try making a bug report on the ikvm site.

Comment: links are dead..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will be an easy task to interoperate .net and java. May be you could use sockets, and use them to send messages from one environment to another. It is just an idea, though.

**EDIT:**

*I have found some libs that say they can do this:*

http://www.jnbridge.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Espresso.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CORBA](http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/corbafaq.htm) to "call" java methods from .NET.

For .NET [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341038/corba-from-net-disrecommended-libraries) you can find some CORBA libraries.

Java SDK includes CORBA capabilities so you don't have to download 3rd party libraries.