# How to pass dictionary in c# as parameter to the soap web service method implemented in java

Tags: java, .net, web-services, c#-4.0

How to pass dictionary in c# as parameter to the soap web service method implemented in java.

I create a soap web service with following method in java:

```
public void webs(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map2)
    {     
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> map1=new Hashtable<String, Map<String, String>>(); 
        
        map1=map2;
      
        for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry:map1.entrySet())
        {    
            String key=entry.getKey();  
            Map<String, String> k=entry.getValue();  
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry1:k.entrySet())
            { 
                String key2=entry1.getKey();
                String Value=entry1.getValue();
                System.out.println(key+" Details:"); 
                System.out.println(key2+" "+Value+" "); 
                
                
            }
             
        }
    }
```

Calling a webservice method as follows:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> MandatoryAttributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
           

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Attributes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Attributes.Add("1", MandatoryAttributes); 
            

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> ListofAttributes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();

            ListofAttributes.Add("ASY-001", Attributes);
            ListofAttributes.Add("PRT-001", Attributes);
            ServiceReference1.DataClient j = new ServiceReference1.DataClient();

            j.webs(ListofAttributes);


        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaM0K.png)

I am not able to pass dictionary as parameter here, Please check attach image for error details.

Questions:
1] How to pass dictionary as parameter in c# to a we method from java soap web service.
2] Will this approach work, Means if I am able to pass dictionary to web-method will it come in java code in same format?
3]Is there any better approach to do so.

Comment: Why I am not getting answers on my questions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Java Method from API in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928200/call-java-method-from-api-in-net)